# loading data by id from SQL DB using php and ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I want to be able to load data into certain html elements from the database using php and ajax.

I want to be able to click different links and this loads different information. Each of these different links will load data from the sql table by ID.

For example:

Say I have 2 links, one called "first" and one called "second". When I click "first", I want to be able to display all the records in the table with the id of 1. When I click "second", I want to display all the records in the table with id 2.

I'm not sure how to do this.

If anyone could tell me the steps involved in doing this, that would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- send the param for the query through ajax to the php script
- query your database based on the data passed to the php script.
- retrieve the query result and separate them using any separator like || for a row and | for individual columns for each row.
- echo the final string. **only one echo**
- in your `onreadystatechange` in ajax, use the `split()` to separate the data in a loop.
- you can now display the results in HTML using the innerHTML in js.